# How can I find this derivative

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $$\tau=F(\nu)$$

How do I check if F satisfies a differential equation $\frac{d\nu}{d\tau}$?  Normally I could find nu in terms of tau, but F is extremly complicated.

Here are my functions
$\tau=1/4\,\ln  \left( u \right) +1/4\,\ln  \left( u-K_{{2}}-2+\sqrt {{
u}^{2}-2\,uK_{{2}}-4\,u+{K_{{2}}}^{2}+4\,K_{{2}}-4\,{\it K2}} \right) 
-1/4\, \left( K_{{2}}+2 \right) \operatorname{arctanh} \left( {\frac { \left( K
_{{2}}+2 \right)  \left( u-K_{{2}}-2 \right) +4+4\,K_{{2}}}{K_{{2}}
\sqrt {{u}^{2}-2\,uK_{{2}}-4\,u+{K_{{2}}}^{2}}}} \right) {K_{{2}}}^{-1
}+1/4\,{\frac {K_{{2}}-\sqrt {{u}^{2}-2\,uK_{{2}}-4\,u+{K_{{2}}}^{2}}}
{u}}$

and the differential equation is
${\frac {d}{d\tau}}{\it u_0} \left( \tau \right) -{\it u_0} \left( \tau
 \right)  \left( {\it u_0} \left( \tau \right) -K_{{2}}+\sqrt { \left( 
{\it u_0} \left( \tau \right)  \right) ^{2}-2\,{\it u_0} \left( \tau
 \right) K_{{2}}+{K_{{2}}}^{2}-4\,{\it u_0} \left( \tau \right) }
 \right) =0
$

Comment: I don't understand the equations you've written, but one starting point you might find helpful is that $\frac{da}{db}\frac{db}{da} = 1.$

Comment: Yea, the equations are stupid.

The first equation is the solution to the differential equation.  I just want to check that by substituting it in maple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $d\tau =F^\prime(\nu)d\nu$, so that you can test your solution by substituting $\frac{d\nu}{d\tau}=\frac 1{F^\prime(\nu)}$ in your equation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: He asked for a metod to testing an implicit solution of a differential equation. I suggest him a substitution; I think that this is an answer. I do not critique nor request clarification.

Comment: Though this was not exactly what I was looking for, it gave me something to pursue.  Thanks